# How to make exceptions to bind-key* overriding behavior?

Tags: minibuffer, bind-key.el

I like binding `M-n` to *make-frame*, so I have the following in my init file:

```
(bind-key* "M-n" 'make-frame)
```

The `*` form of *bind-key* allows me to override other minor-mode `M-n` bindings. But when I'm using the minibuffer (e.g. *find-file*), I'd rather `M-n` retained it's original behavior and ran `next-history-element`.

I'm currently using a workaround, but I'm hoping there's a better solution.

```
(defun ivan-unbind-make-frame () (bind-key* "M-n" nil))
(defun ivan-rebind-make-frame () (bind-key* "M-n" 'make-frame))

(add-to-list 'minibuffer-setup-hook #'ivan-unbind-make-frame)
(add-to-list 'minibuffer-exit-hook  #'ivan-rebind-make-frame)
```

Another approach I considered was to create a keymap of the minibuffer bindings I want to take precedence over *bind-key** bindings and put it in an entry at the front of *emulation-mode-map-alists*.

```
(defvar overriding-minibuffer-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "M-n") #'next-history-element)
    map))

(defvar minibuffer-active-p nil)

(add-to-list 'emulation-mode-map-alists
             `((minibuffer-active-p . ,overriding-minibuffer-map)))

(defun minibuffer-active-on  () (setq minibuffer-active-p t))
(defun minibuffer-active-off () (setq minibuffer-active-p nil))

(add-to-list 'minibuffer-setup-hook #'minibuffer-active-on)
(add-to-list 'minibuffer-exit-hook  #'minibuffer-active-off)
```

This is more complicated and still doesn't free me from using minibuffer setup/exit hooks (unless there's an existing variable that reflects whether the minibuffer is active, but I couldn't find one). It also makes the assumption that `M-n` runs *next-history-element* in all minibuffer use-cases, and I'm not sure that's true.

Is there a better way to handle this, or should I stick with my current solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `PREDICATE` argument of `bind-key*`

```
(bind-key* KEY-NAME COMMAND &optional PREDICATE)

Similar to ‘bind-key’, but overrides any mode-specific bindings.

(bind-key KEY-NAME COMMAND &optional KEYMAP PREDICATE)
[...]

If PREDICATE is non-nil, it is a form evaluated to determine when
a key should be bound. It must return non-nil in such cases.[...]
```

Therefore `(bind-key* "M-n" 'make-frame (not (minibufferp)))` should do what you want.

The predicate parameter is a wrapper around Emacs' filtered keybindings (see [(elisp) Extended Menu Items](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Extended-Menu-Items.html), [Define context-aware keys in Emacs](http://endlessparentheses.com/define-context-aware-keys-in-emacs.html), [Elisp: Conditionally change keybinding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22863701/319698)).

Comment: Wow, that's perfect (I should've rtfd :D) -- thanks. I'm actually using `bind-keys*` (plural), so I ended up with:
`(bind-keys* :filter (not (minibufferp)) ("M-n" . make-frame))`.